# DSYMs Issue in Xcode12.x

Tags: swift, xcode12

Getting this "error: The folder “dSYMs” doesn’t exist." on installing app as well as archiving the app to create ipa file.
Xcode 12.4 specifically.

Appericiate any help.

Comment: Any update on this? this is happening to me as well, on Xcode 12.5. First time I've ever seen this error, can't seem to find any mention of it anywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, here is my analysis.

In my case, xcframework files that I imported from external project causes problem.
First time I added them to my project, they have dSYM files in dSYMs folder of xcframework file, but after I commit them with .gitignore file that ignores dSYM files, dSYMs has gone forever because my .gitignore has following.

```
## App packaging
*.ipa
*.dSYM.zip
*.dSYM
```

After that I made a `git pull` and tried to build, it causes this error, "The folder “dSYMs” doesn’t exist."

I rebuilt external xcframeworks with dSYMs and added following line into my .gitignore.

```
!**/*.xcframework/**/*.dSYM
```

The problem has been solved.
I am not sure it is a right solution but hope it helps you.

Comment: This saved me, thanks for taking the time to post it.  Added the line to my gitignore, pushed it to GitHub, built again, and voila.